# Create a derby database from existing files

Tags: derby

My question is very simple.. I obviously have a folder containing a derby database :
- 3 folders (log - seg0 - tmp)
- db.lck
- service.properties

in seg0 : a list of dat files

How to I use it ? how do I integrate it in Netbeans ? how my application can use the database ?

I imagine it has to be put on a server ? what server ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of the db.lck file indicates that the database was not shut down properly the last time it was used, which means there is a non-zero probability that the database is damaged.

Still ... nothing wrong in trying to access it.

Simply install a copy of Derby, bring up the IJ tool, and type

```
connect 'jdbc:derby:/full/path/to/the/database/folder';
```

You can get Derby from http://db.apache.org/derby.

If you don't know how to run 'ij', look in the Derby documentation for the Derby tutorial, and work through it; then go back to trying to open your database.

Comment: Thank you... what you say probably works well. But if you have netbeans you just find out where the derby server is located : right click on JavaDB in the services window and you can put your folder there